# Is it possible to separate <form> tag from component

Tags: angular

I have a form component that I use in 2 differents places. The only difference is that they belongs to differents forms.

So, I tried to extract  tag from component, and now I have

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-my-component-with-inputs></app-my-component-with-inputs>
</form>
```

If I keep the form inside the component, I will have:

My Component

```
<form "name"="mycomponent">
  <input1>
  <input2
  <input3...>
</form>
```

First Usage of my component

```
<app-my-component-with-inputs></app-my-component-with-inputs>
```

Everything is fine for the first usage.

But for the second usage, the component is already inside a bigger form, so with the form inside, I will have :

```
<form name="form2">
  <input3>
  <input4>
  <input5>
  <!-- if I put <form> tag inside the component, I will have 2 <form> in my second usage -->
  <app-my-component-with-inputs></app-my-component-with-inputs> 
</form>
```

But then, when I click submit button, inside component, it doesn't trigger the onSubmit Method ( which I understand, as it is not anymore part of the component)

How should I do to trigger the onSubmit() method ?

Is it ok to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: in form2, do u need to check any validation for <input3>, <input4>,   <input5>, i mean any of these fields are mandatory or valid email etc.

Comment: yes, I have 3 mandatory fields, 1 name, and 2 dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For common controls, I think you should create a custom component implementing ControlValueAccessor as below:

https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73

so you can use as below:

component1.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-my-component-with-inputs [(ngModel)]="model"></app-my-component-with-inputs>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

component1.ts

```
onSubmit() {
    // use form model
}
```

component2.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit2()">
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.data1" name="data1">
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.data2" name="data2">
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.data3" name="data3">
    <app-my-component-with-inputs [(ngModel)]="model.submodel"></app-my-component-with-inputs>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

component2.ts

```
onSubmit2(data) {


}
```

Comment: Yep ! I seemed complicated, but it is relatively painless!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you need to show same form on multiple pages, you can take form tag inside your component, now to trigger onSumit function use @output as follows:

Main component1 ts file add

```
@Output('onSave') onSave = new EventEmitter();
onSubmit() {
    this.onSave.emit(this.model);   // model hold your form model data
}
```

Main component1 html file

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
...
</form>
```

component1.html

```
<app-my-component-with-inputs (onSave)="onSubmit($event)"></app-my-component-with-inputs>
```

component1.ts

```
onSubmit(data) {
    // use form data
}
```

component2.html

```
<app-my-component-with-inputs (onSave)="onSubmit2($event)"></app-my-component-with-inputs>
```

component2.ts

```
onSubmit2(data) {
    // use form data
}
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, I updated question. I extracted the <form> tag to avoid having in one case 2 <form> tags in the same form